# Complexity of Approximating Vandermonde Determinant

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

Given an $n\times n$ Vandermonde integer matrix with structured integers (such as arithmetic or geometric progression).

Is complexity of approximately computing Vandermonde determinant upto multiplicative error $\epsilon_m$ and additive error $\epsilon_a$ studied in literature?

Comment: Why would you want an approximation, there is an explicit formula for the determinant as a product of $O(n^2)$ numbers.

Comment: true.. if the number had structure, could we do better? without structure we cannot do better.